# startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, cllocationmanager, location-services

I'd added CLLocationManager in my app using Swift in the AppDelegate file.

In the Appdelegate.swift file,

```
import CoreLocation
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
```

In the didbecomeActive method:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    if((locationManager) != nil)
    {
        locationManager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        locationManager.delegate = nil
        locationManager = nil
    }
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.activityType = CLActivityType.OtherNavigation
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
}
```

If I use `startUpdatingLocation`, `didUpdateLocations` method gets called, but not for `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`.

Why it's not getting called for `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`.
I'm testing this in ios simulator. I don't know how to check in device.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682683/can-i-test-significant-change-with-xcode-simulator

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's working, but it's really hard to trigger significant location changes - it usually happens when the device is changing cell towers - I don't think it's possible to do with the simulator.

You'd probably have to get on a bike/car and travel AT LEAST a few kilometres.

There's a trick you can use though, that will trigger significant location change:

Switch Airplaine mode in your iPhone on and off with a few second intervals repeatedly, it should trick the device into thinking that it changed cell towers and trigger the significant location change.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you'd have to travel a few kilometres - enough to trigger a cell tower change.

Comment: remember to spam that airplane button :D It should after a couple of switches.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. saved my life

Comment: Lifesaver - awesome!

Answer (score 3):

In your simulator, goto Debug->Location->Custom and change location, then test it.

Answer (score 2):

In your simulator, select **Features -> Location -> Freeway Drive**

Wait a bit for `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` to trigger `didUpdateLocations`.

Answer (score 0):

> Note:
>   Apps can expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500 meters or more from its previous notification. It should not expect notifications more frequently than once every five minutes. If the device is able to retrieve data from the network, the location manager is much more likely to deliver notifications in a timely manner. [startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati)