# iOS swift Location Manager not getting updated properly

Tags: ios, swift

I am using `CLLocationManager` for getting user location. I need to update user location when they move. I am using this code :

```
import UIKit

import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    lazy var locations = [CLLocation]()
    var op:String = ""
    @IBOutlet weak var resultTxt: UITextView!

    @IBAction func Start(sender: AnyObject) {
        startLocationManager()
        showResult()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func startLocationManager(){
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func startLocationTracking() {
        NSLog("startLocationTracking")
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
            case .NotDetermined, .Restricted, .Denied:
                print("No access")
                self.startLocationManager()
            case .AuthorizedAlways, .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
                NSLog("authorizationStatus authorized")
            }
        } else {
            print("Location services are not enabled")
            self.startLocationManager()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        for location in locations {
            let howRecent = location.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow

            if abs(howRecent) < 10 && location.horizontalAccuracy < 20 {
                //update distance
                self.locations.append(location)
                showResult()
            }
        }
    }

    func showResult(){
        let currentDate = NSDate()
        let res:String = "Result LAT : \(self.locations.last?.coordinate.latitude) AND LNG : \(self.locations.last?.coordinate.longitude)  Time : \(currentDate.toShortTimeString()) \n "
        op += res
        self.resultTxt.text = op
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

And I have already added `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in .plist.
This code works fine for the first time. But when the user moves "`didUpdateLocations`" is not getting fired.
Can any one please help me, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these lines, to be able to monitoring significant location changes when user moves:

```
locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
locationManager.distanceFilter = 300 //value is up to you
```

Comment: Have you tried to simulate location changes? It could be done directly in iOS Simulator.

Comment: Ya... I am testing it on device

Comment: I see, ok, maybe the distance that you did is not enough to fire the location update?...

Comment: May be.. But I am using locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone. And I also commented this line ... if abs(howRecent) < 10 && location.horizontalAccuracy < 20

Comment: Sorry I can't find - where are you calling this function `startLocationTracking()` ?

Comment: I am calling the method on a button press.   @IBAction func Start(sender: AnyObject) {
        startLocationManager()
        showResult()
    }

Comment: Try to check `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()` value before calling `startLocationManager()`

Comment: So the status is .AuthorizedAlways or .AuthorizedWhenInUse right?

Comment: Ok, sorry have no ideas, try to delete and install app from scratch. And take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286288/startmonitoringsignificantlocationchanges-not-working-in-swift