# Why are SLC updates always 5 minutes?

Tags: ios, location, ios-simulator, cllocationmanager

Both on the simulator and the device, my delegate for LocationManager is getting didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation: exactly every 5 minutes while traveling while monitoring SLC. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [CLLocationManager Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html):

> For applications that do not need a regular stream of location events,
>   consider using the startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges method to
>   start the delivery of events instead. This method is more appropriate
>   for the majority of applications that just need an initial user
>   location fix and need updates only when the user moves a significant
>   distance. This interface delivers new events only when it detects
>   changes to the device’s associated cell towers, resulting in less
>   frequent updates and significantly lower power usage.

My guess is that when your app is running in the background, iOS only "wakes" the app every 5 minutes to check whether you have made a Significant Location Change, in order to conserve battery life

There might be some useful information for you also in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158304/trigger-significant-location-change-manually).